# Whats going on at Thicket Excavations?

Tags: fallout-4

This was one of the first places I encountered after leaving the vault, and some guy there wanted my help fixing some broken pipes.  I couldn't pass the persuasion check at the time so he wouldn't explain what his plan was.  After a long time has passed, I finally went by there again and discovered a huge pit filled with raiders and legendary mirelurks, but the mirelurks weren't hostile to me.

What exactly was going on in this pit?  I explored it and killed everything in it but wasn't able to find any terminals or notes of any kind explaining what was going on.

Comment: I did this at a mates house, but there **is** a terminal. Its in a shack not far off the NPC that gives you the quest

Comment: @Timelord64 that terminal was never updated with what was going on after the water was drained, the entries in there remained exactly the same as before, and the latest entry only says he needs to find someone to help him repair the pipes, nothing else

Comment: I'd assume the mirelurks came in and killed him. Then raiders found the area and moved in, only to find the mirelurks and fight them as well.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill nope, from what I can see they were coexisting at the bottom of the place, that's why I'm curious whats going on.  It almost looks like they were farming mirelurks

Comment: It sounds like a matter of "I dont understand" as opposed to "I couldnt find anything". It seemed pretty obvious to me, but apparently not. @VanBuzzKill is slightly off. But it contains spoilers, so don't say I didnt warn ya.

Comment: Im yet to complete this part on my main. Will update the answer with more sources as I go, since I'm practically up to it, now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pass the persuasion test in the initial conversation, Sully simply remarks that he might want to use the quarry to dump bodies.

To quote the fallout wiki;

> After the player character completes the Pull the Plug quest and leaves the quarry, upon returning after a while, they will find that it has become occupied by a large band of raiders. Descending to the bottom will lead to a confrontation with a masked, well-armored Sully Mathis, who may be difficult to defeat at lower levels. If the Sole Survivor found Sully's journal holotape, they can discern he was already a Raider.

Comment: thats kinda lame, i was hoping there was a deeper story to this one, that pit is pretty nifty looking and those non hostile mirelurks were sure easy to kill :)

Comment: I think it was intended as an early mission. I personally felt a bit jipped, too.